# Распространение действия функции-перегрузки операции вызова функции на другие функции этого же класса с++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Хочу в функции перегрузить операцию вызова функции `()` для обращения к элементам массива, заменив привычные `[]` на `()`, т.е. `array[a][b]` на `array(a,b)`. Но сложность вызывает следующее: как сделать, чтобы действие этой перегруженной операции распространялось и на другие функции этого же класса, например, при инициализации массива?

```
const int n=5;
const int m=3;

class Array
{
public:
    Array()
    {
        ptr = new int*[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            ptr[i] = new int[m];
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            delete[]ptr[i];
        }
        delete[]ptr;
    }

    int &operator()(int x, int y)
    {return ptr[x][y];}

    void output()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            for(int  j=0; j<m; ++j){
                ptr[i][j] = rand()%10;
                cout << ptr[i,j] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

protected:
    int **ptr;
};
```

Как сделать, чтобы перегрузка работала и в функции `output`?
Вопрос чисто теоретический. Возможно ли реализовать это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегруженные операторы можно вызывать напрямую, например

```
operator()(i, j) = rand()%10;
cout << operator()(i, j) << "  ";
```

Либо, можно использовать `this`:

```
(*this)(i, j) = rand()%10;
```

Хотя конечно удобнее использовать вспомогательную функцию

```
private:
  int& at_(int x, int y) { return ptr[x][y]; }
public:
  int& operator()(int x, int y) { return at_(x, y); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. `operator()` перегружен для типа `Array`, то и использовать его надо с этим типом, а не встроенным указателем. Т.е. вместо `ptr[i,j]` (что само по себе ошибочно) использовать запись `(*this)(i, j)`.